# Delete lines with other date

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, split

I have a lot of lines like that

```
PrId    Name  Quantity  Price   Date
  3     Milk    2        100   23-08-15
```

that i import from a txt file
i made all the lines string and made all parametrs for each like

```
id is lines[i].Split('\t')[0]
Name is lines[i].Split('\t')[1]
Quantity is lines[i].Split('\t')[2]
Price is lines[i].Split('\t')[3]
and date is lines[i].Split('\t')[4]
```

how i can delete all the lines except that lines that have date 23-08-15

Answer (score 1):

Use can use simple `Linq` statements.

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("23-08-15", "dd-MM-yy", null);

var filterdLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"inputfile")
                .Where(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s.Split('\t')[4], "dd-MM-yy", null) == date)
                .ToList();

File.WriteAllLine("outputfile", filterdLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps:

**1) Identifying lines with date `23-08-15`.**. This can be done using [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
DateTime buffer;
bool parseOk = DateTime.TryParseExact(lines[i].Split('\t')[4], "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, null, out buffer);

if (buffer != new DateTime(2015, 08, 23))
    // skip the line
```

**2) write back filtered lines.** It is unclear if this is required, but if you have to write lines back the file, you can to this using

```
File.WriteAllLines("outputfile", filteredLines);
```